# jQuery UI Autocomplete JSON bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

When you have a remote datasource and min character limit, typing a few letters, deleting them, then typing the same ones gives no results. You can see this on the example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote - try typing 'pi' (get results), delete it and type it again (no results).

Can anyone fix it or work out how to log this bug without becoming a member of the jQuery development team?

Comment: It appears that the problem doesn't occur when the user types 3 characters and backspaces to two, or when they use three characters again. It's only two characters that appears to have the issue.

Comment: @altCognito as Ian said the problem occurs when the minlenght is specified and use the minlength number of chras. In this case the minlenght is 2.

Comment: I guess I need to check the code myself, then... Can't leave that bug in a real website.
@altCognito how odd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log the bug youself at: [jQuery UI BugTracker](http://dev.jqueryui.com/). You need to register. You do not need to become a member of the jQuery development team.

Comment: Right. I'll do that then, re-reading my original post I sounded very petulant, apologies. I just meant that obviously they don't want spam, but seems like if they want people to help out with bug reports, a lower bar would be nice :)